# Balancing adaptive size fonts (UIFontMetrics) with UIView sizes?

Tags: ios, uiview, accessibility, uifont, dynamic-type-feature

I have integrated `UIFontMetrics` into my app, this works fine, but in many cases my strings are trimmed with `...` where the new size exceeds bounds of the view.

Now the issue here is I can't blow my UI up to be massive based around the font size, so how do I handle accommodating when a user picks the max text size for their system without destroying my strings or UI?

No code on this one as it's more of a theoretical question regarding approach.

I suppose I could get a maximum size on everything. But it seems to defeat the point.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have three options:

1. Setup your labels to be multiline and have them adapt their size to fit any sized text.
2. Keep fixed size labels but allow the font size to auto adjust so the text can shrink to fit the size.
3. Do what you are doing and let the text be truncated. Of course within this option you can choose whether the text is truncated at the start, middle, or end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate the `Dynamic Type` in your iOS app, you should adapt your UI accordingly.

Many simple rules must be followed like updating the alignment from horizontal to vertical if needed, avoiding truncation... and you destroy nothing, you just adapt them to the praiseworthy purpose of `Dynamic Type`.

These rules are well explained in this detailed [WWDC video](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html) where all the contents and their video timelapses are indicated to reach rapidly the information.